# How to manage shared package versions across repositories (without making a monorepo)?

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, repository, package.json

Managing a complex frontend project with several feature-modules that are stored in different github repositories. However, we also have a shared components library in its own repo. Because of the shared components we need to keep certain core packages in sync with the version numbers e.g., typescript, react, webpack, etc. However, following micro-services architecture we also want to allow different repos to manage their packages nad versions (outside the core dependencies).

What are the different strategies for having shared dependencies with separate repos. I know that a lot of teams us a monorepo to solve this problem, but that solution might not be an good option for us.

A couple of ideas.

1. Use a git submodule to store shared config and a package.json template. Then use a pre-install hook or install script to enforce the package versions and copy the configs.
2. Have a dependency that sort of encapsulates all the core packages and reference those core dependencies in that shared package. The thing I'm not sure about with this approach is how it work for peer dependencies.

Any insights into these approaches or other strategies would be most welcome. It would be nice to understand the pros and cons of the different approaches as well.